# Is there any harm in taking a melatonin supplement every night?

Tags: sleep, endocrinology, supplement, frequency, melatonin

I noticed that a bottle of melatonin supplement is labelled *"For Occasional Sleeplessness"*.  The use of the word *"Occasional"* surprised me.

Is there any harm in an adult taking a melatonin supplement every night?

Comment: Interesting. I'd interpret "for occasional sleeplessness" as "if you suffer from more than that, get something else / see a doctor, because this won't solve your problem", not as "this isn't safe for long-term use". That I'd expect to be addressed in much stronger language ("not recommended for long-term usage", for example)

Comment: This is also a duplicate, I think, of https://health.stackexchange.com/questions/4389/what-are-the-long-term-side-effects-of-melatonin , but that hasn't yet been answered