# Melatonin to reduce the amount of sleep

Tags: sleep, dosage, melatonin, nootropic-smart-drugs

I noticed that after taking 1mg melatonin I tend to wake up earlier.
Is melatonin a reliable and safe way to reduce the amount of sleep you need? What's a good dose? I am a long sleeper, without any nootropics I need at least 9 hours.

Comment: Please edit your question for it to include all of your current medication.

Comment: FYI [What are the long-term side effects of melatonin?](http://health.stackexchange.com/q/4389/43)